# Не работает SetWorldTransform из winAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, embarcadero

Пишу программу на С++ в Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2. Пытаюсь получить изображение с usb камеры и повернуть его на заданный углы. Для работы с камерами использую функции WinAPI. Функция SetWorldTransform возвращает 0 (соответственно изображение не трансформируется), при этом GetLastError возвращает 0. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано. За поворот отвечает метод ConcreteCamStreamer::RotateWindow:

```
void ConcreteCamStreamer::RotateWindow(int _angle)
{
    HDC hdc = GetDC(this->captureWindowHwnd_);

    XFORM xForm;

    xForm.eM11 = (FLOAT) 0.8660;
    xForm.eM12 = (FLOAT) 0.5000;
    xForm.eM21 = (FLOAT) -0.5000;
    xForm.eM22 = (FLOAT) 0.8660;
    xForm.eDx  = (FLOAT) 0.0;
    xForm.eDy  = (FLOAT) 0.0;

    if (ModifyWorldTransform(hdc, &xForm, MWT_RIGHTMULTIPLY) != 0)
    {
        ShowMessage("Got it!");
    }
    else
    {
        ShowMessage("Ooooops");
    }

    ReleaseDC(this->captureWindowHwnd_, hdc);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли установить SetGraphicsMode c GM_ADVANCED

Comment: Он устанавливается в конструкторе класса.

Comment: @user1683303 Он не может устанавливаться в конструкторе класса, так как контекст захватывается и освобождается внутри этой функции.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что при каждом захвате контекста устройства (через GetDC() в моем случае) надо устанавливать этот режим?

Comment: Совершенно верно. Каждый раз при захвате в контексте установлены параметры по умолчанию (кисть, шрифт, перо, преобразование). Если изменяемых параметров очень много, то можно сохранять состояние один раз SaveDC и потом RestoreDC (ну это редко требуется)

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь функция SetWorldTransform возвращает ненулевое значение, из чего делаю вывод о том, что функция отработала как следует. Но при этом нет никаких изменений в окне. Попробовал вызвать функции RedrawWindow и UpdateWindow. Результата не дало.

Comment: Так... Эти функции вызывают WM_PAINT для окна, ваша функция тут получается не при делах. Всю отрисовку положено делать внутри обработчика WM_PAINT (в OnPaint в Delphi/Builder), где заново захватывается контекст и ваши параметры преобразования уже не действуют. Возможно, проблему можно решить костылем с перекрытием SetParams стиля окна со включённым CS_OWNDC, но лучше традиционным способом всё же пользоваться (всё рисование и сопутствующие действия в ONPaint)

Comment: Кстати, раз уж вы в билдере - возьмите битмап,  все параметры для него установите, и на нём всегда рисуйте, а в OnPaint будете только шлёпать его на нужный контекст. Что-то меня не туда понесло, а это, вообще говоря, самая стандартная схема работы (в том числе и без использования VCL-ного битмапа, с  созданием DIB/CompatibleDC)

Comment: А создание и работа с несколькими Bitmap'ами не будет бить по производительности?

Comment: Нет, не будет. Одного битмапа размером с область отрисовки достаточно. Если окно или область отрисовки меняет размер, то соответственно нужно менять и размер битмапа.